# How to get latest subdirectory created in project folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the last modified directory of a folder in the project directory. With the code below, I can get the last modified directory only for the scripts saved in the directory, but I want to get the last modified `subdir` of a folder, which is in project directory.

And I only want to fetch the folder name, not the whole path, because I will increment the folder name `+1` and create new one when the file limit is reached for the mentioned folder.

And my code is:

```
import os
import glob


all_subdirs = [d for d in os.listdir('/root/visual-
studio/testfolder/testsubdir/') if os.path.isdir(d)]
latest_subdir = max(all_subdirs, key=os.path.getmtime)

print(latest_subdir)
```

The script is saved to `testfolder` and when I run the script it only gives `testfolders` last modified directory. But I want to get the `testsubdirs` latest directory.

When I run the script below for `testsubdirs` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/visual-studio/testfolder/test.py", line 40, in <module>
    latest_subdir = max(all_subdirs, key=os.path.getmtime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: d is just a filename not a path, you need to concat basedir and filename in your os.path.isdir.  And I don't know why visual-studio is in the root directory :-/

Comment: I am using visual studio for writing scripts. That’s why. :)

Comment: Can you give more detail about d is just a filename not a path section of your comment. @brodeur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T think the problem is `os.path.listdir()` is return just the file or subdirectory name, not the full path to them. This simplest fix is to use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) which returns the full path of matching entries (if there's one in the search pattern, that is):

```
import os
import glob

all_subdirs = [d for d in glob.glob('/root/visual-studio/testfolder/testsubdir/*') 
                if os.path.isdir(d)]

latest_subdir = max(all_subdirs, key=os.path.getmtime)
print(latest_subdir)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but I need last created directory name not the full path to the directory last modified.

Comment: Just use `os.path.basename(latest_subdir)` to remove all but the path name.

Answer (score 0):

@martineau 's gave me clue and I made some digging into library files and found this solution. As I mentioned before I wasn't able to receive the last directory name of the path and not the full path.

So here is the code :

```
import os
import glob

all_subdirs = [d for d in glob.glob('/root/testfolder/testsubdir/*') 
            if os.path.isdir(d)]

latest_subdir = max(all_subdirs, key=os.path.getmtime)
r = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(latest_subdir))
print(r)
```